# jquery automatic dragging event via button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

below is link:
http://liveweave.com/JckSgC

here user can drag drop objects to canvas.

i want to add button such add on button click objects from both sides gets dragged and dropped into canvas no need to drag and drop it with same effect (as dragged dropped using cursor) something like ppt or movie is it possible ?..

i though of animate()

but i need that user can do it manualy or via button click (like quidance how to do), so animate will not work

Comment: why -ve may i have reason ?

Comment: I think you'll need the animate() method for this: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_animate.asp

Comment: yeah but i need both either user can do it mannualy or via button click, so animate will not work